# How much body mass will I lose by switching over from lifting to calisthenics?

Tags: calisthenics, lifting

My current routine is:

Push

- Bench
- Shoulder lat raises
- Shoulder press
- Tricep pushdown
- Pushups

Pull

- Deadlift
- Pullups
- Dumbbell rows
- Hammer curls
- Face pulls

Legs

- Leg press
- Leg extension
- Leg curl
- Leg raises

I would like to switch to an all-calisthenic routine. I will likely start with some variation of the [Beast Mode plan](https://ashotofadrenaline.net/calisthenics-workout-plan/):

[image]
[image]

My question is, how much muscle mass will I lose from this transition? I am currently not a "juicehead" (I am 6'4 and generally bench around 165lbs), but I definitely have gained mass in the year or so I have been lifting. Am I going to lose a significant amount of muscle mass?

Comment: Why would you lose any?

Answer (score 1):

**If your workouts will be as intens as they are now, you won't lose any mass.** It's even possible that you will gain more mass since this will be a new way of stimulating the muscle which your body isn't used to.

I started doing calisthenics myself about 3 years ago and I've gained a more solid body since then. Prior to calisthenics I did about 2,5 years of pure strength training. I have gained more muscle since doing calisthenics.

Comment: Any particular program you would recommend?

Comment: Depends on what your current level of fitness is. If you start from scratch I would recommend first learning the basics properly like pushups, pullups, planks, dips, squats, before moving on to more advanced movements. If you already have some strength from doing regular strength training I would recommend starting out with things like a handstand, L-sit, explosive pullups.